# Apple Configurator 2: Cannot skip "Written and Spoken Languages" in Setup

Tags: ios, apple-configurator

I am using Apple Configurator 2 in combination with MDM from MacOS Server to erase and prepare a supervized iPhone running iOS 14.2.

I can successfully run erase and prepare the device. My goal is to suppress **all** setup dialog panes. I can suppress all of them with the sole exception of "Written and spoken languages" which is still shown despite all my efforts. I use the Gui of Apple Configurator 2 to configure the prepare step and have ticket "Don't show any of these steps" box. The device is enrolled, Apple Business Manager is setup and linked with the MDM an everything looks fine.

It seems to me that this should work. Somebody have an idea or has successfully achieved this?

MacOS Server 5.10 20S2015
Apple Configurator 2 Version 2.13.1
iOS Version 14.2

Comment: Do you supervise the iPhone?

Comment: The iPhone is supervised.

Comment: Bummer, it was a long shot, but worth checking.